# javascript return, not functioning

Tags: javascript, function, return

I have this code:

```
replaceAny('this','that',string);
if(val!="")
```

the replaceAny function looks like this:

```
function replaceAny(first,second,ele) {
  var val = ele.replace(first,second);
  alert(val);
  return val;
}
```

But then after running the replaceAny function (and the alert shows the right value, the if condition tells me that the variable val is not set, why?!

Comment: Your code isn't valid. Please post real code that represents a working example of the problem if you actually have a question.

Comment: It's rather hard to tell what you're asking. Please edit this for clarity or it will probably be closed.

Comment: Problem solved, I did not set the variable's value! i.e. `val=replaceAny();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using the return value from the function correctly.  This is something like what you want

```
function replaceAny(first,second,ele) {
  return ele.replace(first,second);
}

var val = replaceAny('this','that',string);
if(val!=""){
  //something, something darkside
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not assigning the value returned by your function to your variable `val`.

Try like this

```
 val = replaceAny('this','that',string);
 if(val!="")
```